# Declaring autolink in TextView hides the text...!

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, autolink

I'm trying to define autolink = "web" for a TextView. Surprisingly when I declare this, the text in the TextView goes hidded and gets visible only on the first click. This is so astonishing I've the same functionality in many part of my application where it works fine. This is the only place where I couldn't find what the problem is.

Please help me with a solution:

Here's my TextView XML code:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/details_webAddress_textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/details_location_textView"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_website_earth"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:text="www.google.com"
            android:visibility="visible" />
```

Following is the TextView where the autolink works well:

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/websiteAddress_textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:autoLink="web"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="www.stackoverflow.com" />
```

Comment: ... perhaps you should post code pieces from the part where this exact same thing works in other parts of the application as well?

Comment: the reason is `android:singleLine="true"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try use:

```
TextView textLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.details_webAddress_textView);
textLink.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
Button buttonDetails = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

buttonDetails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textLink.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // text visible on firt click
                String url = "http://www.example.com";
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i); // open link with default browser
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Tou need to set the "android:textColorLink" attribute in the xml additionally to the "android:autoLink" attribute.

```
<TextView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:autoLink="web"
     android:textColorLink="@color/yourDesiredLinkColor"/>
```